# What are the orbital perturbations needed to destabilize a system to the point of taking some bodies out of resonance and kicking out another?

Tags: hard-science, orbital-mechanics

I have a gas giant with a mass of $1.63314\times10^{27}kg$ and a radius of 66,559.052km and orbiting it are 4 moons.
It orbits a star with 0.86M☉ at a distance of 5.03AU

My question is what destabilization (the minimum size and ideal speed of a foreign body/the minimum distance of migration by one of the moons) would be needed for the innermost two bodies to leave resonance, the innermost one to migrate outward, and for the second farthest to be ejected out of the system entirely, in a way similar to the five-planet Nice model?

> The innermost one has a mass of 0.81x(the mass of the Moon), a semi-major axis of 343,781km, and an eccentricity of 0.005.
>
> The second closest has a mass of 1.02x(the mass of the Moon) with a semi-major axis of 545,509km which should mean that it is in orbital resonance with the first moon. It has an eccentricity of 0.011.
>
> The second farthest one has a mass of 1.61 Moon masses and a semi-major axis of 871,413.13km. It has an eccentricity of 0.051.
>
> The outermost one has a mass of 1.28 Moon masses and a semi-major axis of 1,436,711.3km. Its eccentricity is 0.063.

P.S. Orbits 2 and 4 can also be affected, just as long as they aren't kicked out. I just don't care on the way they are affected.

P.P.S. Someone in the comments suggested the use of an N-body sim. While I do plan on doing that, I should note that I asked this question in order to potentially recieve a way to narrow down the number of  attempts within the sim. It was a good suggestion, though!

Comment: Can you please identify what you mean by a destabilization? Are you asking what the minimum size and ideal speed is for a foreign body (asteroid or rogue planet) passing by to produce the results you describe? Or are you asking how many moon sized rockets you would need to push the moons into the places you want?

Comment: When you say "two bodies" you specifically mean two moons of the gas giant, right? Of the four moons, you're specifically looking to pull moons #1 (counting from the closest orbit) and #3 out of their orbits, but not moons #2 and #4? And you want to do this with a single rogue object? Do you need a guarantee that moons #2 and #4 *won't be destabilized?* (They'll be affected as the other moons are now gone.) While the orbital periods of the moons could be derived from the data you provided, it would be simpler if you provided that information. Thanks.

Comment: Honestly, this seems like a job for an n-body simulator. There are plenty of things out there... as a starting point, I've used [orbitsimulator](http://www.orbitsimulator.com/gravity/articles/what.html) which can be run in-browser. You can tweak the settings to your hearts content, and given your very specific requirements that's probably the only way of getting an answer that meets all your needs. It is also more likely that you'll simulate it than someone else will simulate it for you and tell you the answer!

Comment: @StarfishPrime is correct. Its just another variant of the tuning fork and vineglass problem. You need to big asteroids flybys at the resonance frequencies of the system and sing it apart by increasing the eccentricity of the orbit.